# Lennard-Jones potential - equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, equilibrium, molecules

If I have Lennard-Jones potential, how can I calculate equilibrium?
$$ U(r)=\epsilon \left ( \left (\frac{r_m}{r} \right )^{12}-2 \left (\frac{r_m}{r}\right )^6 \right ) \ $$

Comment: -Is this a HW question by chance? We don't usually solve HW questions here. If you want a hint, I would sketch a plot of the potential. Particular points should jump out as candidates for an equilibrium positions - if recall your calculus class there is a way to find said points...

Comment: Equilbrium of _what_? Two atoms? Temperature? Zero temperature? Many atoms? fluid? gas? This is not a question as it stands.

Comment: $ \vec F = -{d U \over dr } = 0$

Answer (score 2):

A hint:  The derivative of a potential energy such as $U$ is, with suitable sign, a force.  At equilibrium what should the force be?